# How do you find where a module's directory is located?

Tags: 7

I have the following: [image]

I want to find where the module "commerce_physical" is located in the modules folder, but I can't seem to locate this module. I did a find and a grep to locate where its files might be, but that doesnt seem to work. What are some other ways to find the location of a drupal 7 module?

Comment: If you're using the Kickstart distribution it'll be in profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `{system}` table.  In particular, the `name` column will be the module name (ie, the basename of the .info and .module files).  The `filename` column will be the full filename, with path, to the .info file for the module, relative to the DOCROOT of the installation.  See [`system_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.install/function/system_schema/7) for more information.

Comment: thanks got it!! http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/5786/croppercapture224.jpg